# How many adaptations of his books has John le Carre appeared in?

Tags: book-adaptation, cameo

In the recent BBC TV series adaptation of John le Carre's novel *The Night Manager*, [the man himself made a cameo appearance in one of the scenes](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3510928/Did-spot-John-Le-Carre-Author-s-son-reveals-father-cameo-adaptation-novel-Night-Manager-managed-steal-scene.html), placing his seal of approval on the adaptation. The linked article mentions that he's previously made similar appearances in other televised versions of his books. **How many times has he done this?**

How many film or TV adaptations of le Carre novels have been 'blessed' in this way by the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three times.**

Apart from episode 1.4 of [*The Night Manager* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1399664/) that you already mentioned, John Le Carré appeared as a Christmas party guest in [*Tinker Taylor Soldier Spy* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1340800/) and as "Commander" in [*The Little Drummer Girl* (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087629/), though credited as "David Cornwell".

[image: Screenshot from John Le Carré's IMDb page]

This also means that he exclusively acts in TV shows and movies adapted from his *own* works.